# NativeXML - Create processing instructions (xml-stylesheet)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, nativexml

I know how to do it with 'classic' XML object

```
begin
  piNode := XMLDocument1.DOMDocument.createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 'type="text/xsl"  href="CDA2.xsl"');
  XMLDocument1.DOMDocument.insertBefore(piNode, XMLDocument1.DOMDocument.childNodes[1]);
end;
```

But now I have a project that uses **NativeXML** ; and I don't want to mix the code ; I want to use NativeXML to complete this task.

So ... my question is : Is there a function/method/workaround to do this with NativeXML.

Thank you!

Comment: `NativeXml.StyleSheet.WriteAttributeString('type', 'text/xsl'); NativeXml.StyleSheet.WriteAttributeString('href', 'CDA2.xsl');` `</wild-guess>` :-)

Comment: @TLama : Uhm ; you sure make a good 'wild-guess' ; That did it. funny I didn't saw the StyleSheet property :(  tnx!